# How do I write data to a single column with different indexes?

Tags: r

Everybody. My program counts statistics for all groups. So for example I have groups 1,2,3,4. The program processes in cycles: `1-2`; `1-3`; `1-4`; `2-3`; `2-4`; `3-4`; but NOT columns `2` and `1`, because that's the same as the first pair, etc.

I created a new data set with columns `c('n', 'v', 'd','pv',' pvf')` from `1 to 3`. I would like it to be recorded in this format:
`1:...`
`2:...`
`3:...`
And from 4 to 5:
`1-2:...`
`1-3:...`
`1-4:...`
`2-3:...`
`2-4:...`
`3-4:...`
I wrote a small example:

```
res=list()
for (i in 1:(ncol(mtcars)-1)) {
  for (j in (i+1):ncol(mtcars)) {
    res=c(res,list(c(i,j,paste0(mtcars[,i],'_',mtcars[,j])))
    )
  }
}
res=do.call(cbind,res)
```

How do I write data with different indexes to one cell and glue them together?

Comment: In the form of a table?

Comment: I updated the code a bit for the example, the first time mpg connects to the following metrics (cyl, disp, hp,....) I would like this to be output in a single cell in the format 1: mpg \ n 2: disp \ n 3: hp....

Comment: if you try to run the code from the top, you will get 21_6; 21_160;_21_110; in line 3 ...... I want to write this in a single column without repetitions, like: 1:21; 2:160; 3:110 ....Where 1,23 are the indexes

Comment: why not modify your question.   Just write/type in the expected outcome in the desired format.  Else it will be difficult to understand

Comment: what I wrote I'm trying to get: ) And in the question, the same thing

Comment: in the `paste0`, is your intention to get the column name or all the data of the column as this is written?

Comment: I would like to write columns with different indexes to a single cell